# Return type of array access operator overload

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

I have a class `Foo` that manages a collection of objects of another class `Bar`. The managing class has a method `Bar *Foo::at( int index )` to access the objects int he collection, so I can do something like `myfoo->at(2)->barmethod()`, say. Now I was wondering if I can overload `Foo::operator[]` to return a `Bar*`, so I could do `myfoo[2]->barmethod()` instead. The compiler doesn't like that. Does the return type of the operator necessarily need to be a reference to the class it is a member of?

Here is some code. The first works, the second doesn't.

```
Foo::Bar *Foo::at( size_t index )
{
    return index < m_count ? m_entry[index] : 0;
}

Foo::Bar *Foo::operator[]( size_t index )
{
    return index < m_count ? m_entry[index] : 0;
}
```

From the header:

```
class Foo
{
public:

    class Bar
    {
    ...
    };

    size_t add( UINT8 addr, UINT8 type, UINT8 opt, UINT8 rev );
    Bar    *at( size_t index );
    Bar    *operator[]( size_t index );
    ....

protected:

    Bar             **m_entry;      // array of entry pointers
    size_t          m_size;
    size_t          m_count;

};
```

Here's the code the compiler doesn't like (when using [ ]):

```
Foo *myfoo;
...
myfoo[i]->barmethod();
```

and now in writing this I see what the problem is. I'm using `[]` on a POINTER to a `Foo`, not on an actual `Foo`. So if I dereference it, it should work. The compiler error is exactly right:

*error: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'Foo'*

Duh. Okay, sorry for the dumb question. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Do you actually manage a collection of objects... or a collection of pointers to objects?

Comment: There is no restriction on return type of a function... you made a bug in your code somewhere but it is going to be hard for someone to answer if you don't post your code

Comment: You need to add the error to your question

Comment: @Angew: That's a nice way of thinking about this. Put as an answer?

Comment: @M.M : It is indeed a collection of objects, but they are created internally by `size_t Foo::add()` which takes sufficient args to construct the `Bar` object, and returns the index to the constructed object. I will post some code as you ask.

Comment: @marcinj : Done. And while adding it, I realized what the problem was. +1 for asking me to to what I should have done in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The only thing you can't change when overloading `operator[]` is its *arity*: that is, you can't change the number of parameters.

But you can change the *type* of the parameter (although `std::size_t` is common), and you can change the return type too. (Although `const Bar&` is common for the `const` overload of `[]`, and `Bar&` is common for the non-`const` overload).

Answer (score 4):

> Does the return type of the operator necessarily need to be a reference to the class it is a member of?

You could trivially answer this yourself by thinking about e.g. `std::vector`, its `operator []`, and the return type of the latter.

The conclusion is that there is no such restriction. The only restrictions on `operator[]` are:

- It must take exactly one argument.
- It must be defined as a member function (it cannot be a namespace-scope function).

Comment: Nice. Have an vpvote. The second bullet is in the pub quiz category.